# How to write DRY query to select aggregate along with columns

Tags: mysql

In [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cd93/23) , I'm trying to find the timestamp difference between column's minimum value and column value. This is for normalizing time series data. 
Here's the query:

```
select
  sts1.stock_name, 
  sts1.t- sts2.tmin t0, 
  sts1.value
from (
  select 
    id,
    stock_name, 
    unix_timestamp(query_time) t,
    value
  from sts
  where query_time between '2014-01-24 10:00:01' and '2014-01-24 10:00:08'
) sts1
cross join (
  select  
    min(unix_timestamp(query_time)) tmin
  from sts
  where query_time between '2014-01-24 10:00:01' and '2014-01-24 10:00:08'
) sts2;
```

How can I write this without repeating the where conditions or double joining the same table?

In MSSQL, when you add a `min` column, it doesn't truncate the result set, it just selects `min` along with the data.

Edit

Here's an MSSQL example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79dd0/10

```
select 
  stock_name,
  datediff(second, min(query_time) over (partition by stock_name), query_time) t0,
  value
from sts;
```

Edit

Here's how I did it in postgresql:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/52532/8

```
select 
  stock_name, 
  extract('seconds' from query_time- (min(query_time) over())) t0,
  value 
from sts;
```

Edit

Here's my mysql contraption which does what I want using variables:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27bfe/9

```
select 
  stock_name, 
  case when @c= 0 then @tmin:= query_time else query_time end, 
  @c:= @c+ 1, 
  time_to_sec(timediff(query_time, @tmin)) t0,
  value
from sts
```

Comment: MySQL neither supports window functions nor common table expressions so I don't think there is a way to do what you want.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added a mysql solution using variables